# best practice to cache dynamic content at client side

Tags: php, ajax, caching, optimization

Sorry for that, but i really concluded with the decision that it's better to ask directly than browsing tons of pages in vain.
I've already looked through enough resources, but haven't found a decent explanation that could fulfill my curiosity about simplest question.
Assume there’s a URI located at – `hhtp://example.com/example` (including php script, queries to the database).
Let’s imagine I’ve loaded it in my browser, click some link and hit “back” to return to `hhtp://example.com/example`

As far as I can allow myself  to understand about what happens behind the scene looks smth like this:
After “back” been clicked there browser checks its cache specifically `hhtp://example.com/example` which matches exactly to the requested file (after “back”) and finds out that it wasn’t changed within this short period of time since it was first time loaded and returns it from its cache.

Wait!!!!
The file contains server side scripts, database queries and so forth. 
So it should again reach web server, request same data from mysql and output it in a file.

So what’s the best strategy to cache dynamic content preferably on client-side vs server-side?
In which cases it makes useful to cache content at server-side, and what practice is the best?

Please can someone provide some resources covering this subject that can be conceived by such dumpers like my and refute or adjust the scheme above about what actually happens.

While browsing the issue i run into one service - http://gtmetrix.com/  I liked very much,
There were smth mentioned about making ajax request cacheable – I may assume that it can be perfectly used  for client-side caching of dynamic content retrieved from database. Can someone please acknowledge it or deprecate?

Comment: If something is cached it doesn't check whether it is changed. It simply checks whether the cache is still valid (often base on a timestamp)

Comment: Is the server, using [HTTP caching](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html), to tell the browser if the page has to be cached and long to wait before reloading it. Using `header` instruction in PHP you can explicitly define whether a page has to be cached or not. However, a browser may be configured to remove cached elements before of their expiration.

Comment: Database access are usually slow. If you can cache the results that's a big difference, and more if the queries are complex. You don't need to cache all the page, but the slow parts of it.

Comment: So, if I can cache the result of the database query on client side, can I retrieve specific items asking it in the same way or similar to  standard database query?